# Set the correct server request path

Tags: javascript, server, express.js

Can this `if-else` statement be simplified and/or cleaned up?

```
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  var page;
  if (req.params[0] === '') {
    // if requesting root dir, add `index.html`
    page = path.parse(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  } else {
    // otherwise add requested path
    page = path.parse(path.join(__dirname, req.params[0]))
    if (page.ext === '') {
      // if requested page has no extension, change page, adding `index.html`
      page = path.parse(path.join(__dirname, req.params[0], 'index.html'))
    }
  }
  if (page.ext === '.html') {
    /*... do html stuff ...*/
  }
  else if (page.ext === '.css') {
    /*... do css stuff ...*/
  }
  /*...*/
})
```

It works correctly but I feel it’s "bad coding". There are nested `if` statements and I’m repeating a lot of code. Also, below the first condition, there are other conditions testing the type of page (HTML, CSS, etc.) Since in the `page.ext===''` condition, the value of `page` may change, it's not a mutually exclusive case of the other conditions.

It’s weird and feels wrong, but I can’t quite explain why.

I tried using the ternary expression (`?:`), but I still can’t avoid the `if` statement afterward.

```
var page = path.parse(path.join(__dirname, (req.params[0] === '') ? 'index.html' : req.params[0]))
if (page.ext === '') page = path.parse(path.join(__dirname, req.params[0], 'index.html'))
```

Is there a way to do it without repeating code? I’d like to avoid assigning `page` more than once.

---

+++
I’ve come up with a less verbose way of doing it, and it only requires assigning `page` once. Though it still requires calling `path.parse()` more than once.

```
var filepath = path.join(__dirname, req.params[0] || 'index.html')
var page = path.parse(path.join(filepath, (path.parse(filepath).ext === '') ? 'index.html' : ''))
```

---

+++
After discovering `path.extname(<String>)`, I realized I don’t need to parse it beforehand. So this simplifies to:

```
var filepath = path.join(__dirname, req.params[0] || 'index.html')
var page = path.parse(path.join(filepath, (path.extname(filepath) === '') ? 'index.html' : ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider building an array of path segments through your logic and then setting `page` with it.

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  var page
  var base = req.params[0]
  var baseExtension = path.parse(base).ext
  // determine path segments
  var pathSegments = [__dirname]
  if (base !== '') {
    pathSegments.push(base)
  }
  if (baseExtension === '') {
    pathSegments.push('index.html')         
  }

  // set page
  // here we use spread operator
  page = path.parse(path.join(...pathSegments))
  // if not using ES6, you could alternatively use
  // page = path.parse(path.join.apply(pathSegments))

  // perhaps consider switch here instead of if-else if you are going
  // to have more than just html and css extension types
  if (page.ext === '.html') {
    /*... do html stuff ...*/
  }
  else if (page.ext === '.css') {
    /*... do css stuff ...*/
  }
  /*...*/
})
```

Be consistent on your usage or non-usage of semicolons to end lines of code.  It seems like you have chosen to use the no semi-colon style, so why is there one after `var page;`?

Comment: I usually stick to the no-semicolon style, but that semicolon shows the unassigned var isn't a typo

Comment: @chharvey Gotcha. I usually see intentionally inserted semicolons at the start of the following line with this style (which I admit I am not particularly used to using.) but wasn't going to add a code review comment to "add semicolons to every line" as that is really a styling choice a developer or development team needs to make - so long as it is applied consistently.